# Find an equation of the sphere with center $(-3,2,5)$ and radius $4$. What is the intersection of this sphere with the y-z plane?

Tags: calculus, geometry, spheres

I know my equation is $(x+3)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-5)^2=16$ but how do I find the intersection with the y-z plane?

I'm doing some study prep for my upcoming calculus 3 class.

Comment: The $yz$-plane has $x=0$.

Comment: y-z plane takes place when $x= 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $yz$-plane is the plane $x=0.$ So set $x=0$ to your equation and you will get $(y-2)^2 +(z-5)^2=16-9=7$ which is a circle on the $yz$-plane.

Comment: Sorry I'm somewhat confused... Where is the 9 coming from?

Comment: by setting $x=0,$ you get $(0+3)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-5)^2=16$

Comment: Oh duh... Thanks!

Comment: I was setting the entire term to 0